# Group By vs. Join which one takes longer?

Tags: sql, time-complexity

(This question is for self-study).

I have two tables.

A - a table containing the following columns: user, money

B - a table containing the following columns: user, number

money is the dollar amount that the user spent
number is the number of items that the user purchased

A is slightly bigger than B, and A contains all users that B contains while B is missing some users that A has, but A isn't much bigger than B either, like 1.1~1.2 times the size of B.

I wanna have create the table containing the following 3 columns: user, money, number

If the user is not present in table B, then we just use 0 as number.

There're two ways of doing it.

```
Select A.user, A.money, case when B.number is null then 0 else B.number end 
as number from A left join B on A.user=B.user


Select user, max(money), max(number) from
((Select user, money, 0 as number from A) 
union all (Select user, 0 as money, number from B)) 
group by user
```

I was just curious about how to figure out which query would take less time and memory. Is there a good way to calculate it based on the size of tables A or B?

Comment: Not sure but I think it comes down to execution of the query here.  Not only are you doing a Group By but you are also doing a Union.  The Group By I think also has to finish the query first to compare results.  Whereas the join does this much faster.   Why i couldn't tell you in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query should be written as:

```
Select A.user, A.money,
       coalesce(B.number, 0) as number
from A left join
     B
     on A.user = B.user;
```

With an index on `B(user)` or `B(user, number)` this should be the fastest way to do what you want. Without an index there is an "it depends".  You should try on your data.  But a reasonable database will probably do a hash-join for the join, and be faster than the equivalent aggregation.

In addition, doing the `union all` is probably going to preclude the use of indexes.  The resulting aggregation algorithm is going to be slower than a `join` using an index.

Comment: my query works fine as well or is coalesce method something that works faster?

Comment: @user98235 . . . `coalesce()` is simply more concise.